# difference between wrapper class and primitive type definition

Tags: struts2

I am working on Struts 2 and using Eclipselink JPA.

In my entity classes, I have defined a variable of primitive type, i.e `private int ductRun;` and other one of wrapper class type i.e `private Integer ductQty`.
On the JSP page, if user submit the form leaving both the fields blank, the primitive type variables(`ductRun`) gets initialize automatically to "0", and wrapper type variable (`ductQty`) remain null. And the validation ***required*** of struts for field ductRun is not working.

Now I want to know the reason behind it, where is initializing the ductRun and whether it is a good approach to define all the variables in entity class of primitive type.
Hope it is understandable.

Comment: Show your action code and full stacktrace.

Comment: Empty fields has such values until you explicitly initialize them to null. Do it in action by setting some properties before the action invocation.

Comment: Actually I got where I was doing wrong. I have defined that field in my class as `int ductRunQty`, and at that time when i was submitting the form with the blank field, i was getting that error. But When I changed the declaration of my variable to `Integer ductRunQty` , it was working fine. And validation for required field is also working fine. Please can somebody explain me, how we should declare our variables in model class, using wrapper class or using preemptive data type. What is the difference of both the ways